# Store string with placeholder and html tags

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

I want to create a template and store it in the database so later I can load and change the values. It's a simple html. However, I'm unable to set a string with html tags.

```
string verifyEmailTemplate = @"
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset="utf-8" />
                        <title></title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    Some text
                    <p>Thanks,</p>
                    <br />
                    <form action="{baseUrl}/{email}/{emailCode}">
                        <input type="submit" value="Verify Email" />
                    </form>
            </body>
            </html> ";
```

I want to save this as string into database and later load this and replace`{baseUrl}/{email}/{emailCode}`. I have tried to escape all the `"`, but it's still not recoginizing as valid string. Any suggestions?

UPDATE with escape:

```
string verifyEmailTemplate = @"
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html lang=\"en\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\">
                    <head>
                        <meta charset=\"utf-8\" />
                        <title></title>
                    </head>
                    <body>
                    Some text
                    <p>Thanks,</p>
                    <br />
                    <form action=\"{baseUrl}/{email}/{emailCode}\">
                        <input type=\"submit\" value="Verify Email\" />
                    </form>
            </body>
            </html> ";
```

Comment: Post the code you tried with quotes removed.

Comment: Sure, one moment.

Comment: Works for me with every " replaced with ""

Comment: @Charlieface, yes!!! If you put that as an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.